# How to calculate a single step of an rl agent

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, agent

In short, as a beginner, I train with keras a NN with an agent for the Gym CartPole environment.
The model looks like this:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
def build_model(states, actions):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,states))) # for states (=4)
    model.add(Dense(24,activation=activation_function))
    model.add(Dense(24,activation=activation_function))
    model.add(Dense(actions,activation="linear")) # for actions (=2)
    return model
model = build_model(states,actions)
```

, where the environment consists of 4 states and 2 actions.

The agent looks like this:

```
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
# set up an agent:
def build_agent(model,actions):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory = memory, policy = policy,nb_actions = actions, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update =1e-2)                   
    return dqn
# use dqn Agent:
dqn = build_agent(model,actions)
dqn.compile( Adam(lr=1e-3) ,metrics =["mae"])
dqn.fit(env,nb_steps=10000,visualize=False,verbose=1)
```

**My question:** is it possible to calculate the action of the agent for a specific state, e.g.: [0,0,0,0]?

The *dqn.compute_q_values(np.zeros(4))* returns the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_4_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 4).
```